# To use concentric circles on human body canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, css-animations, kineticjs, react-konva

I am working on an application which takes input from the patient on parameters such as Headache, Cold cough etc. For doctors dashboard need to highlight body part with animation (concentric circle) whose radius changes according to input by user. 
Kindly help me with the direction. which framework to be used, how to think about this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is how i would do it: first you need to draw the human body image on the canvas. Next you need to be able to detect the mouse position on the canvas. The user would click the canvas, for example in the case of the headache would click some spot on the image's head. You can push this point together with more data from user (like the intensity of the pain) in an array of objects. Next you draw the circle on the clicked point where the circle's radius  depends on the intensity of the pain.

Comment: I realize this is the second time you are asking the same question. Please dele one of the 2 identical questions

Comment: @enxaneta : Thank you for your advice. I have one query can we have those circles on canvas without user clicking on image much like data visualization. Apologies for duplicate post, I have deleted first one.Will check again if its not deleted.

Comment: In this case you may need an array of positions on the canvas every position with a name. The user may need to select a name, for example `head`. Once selected the program would draw a circle at the predefined coordinates for the `head`

Comment: @enaxaneta: Thanks for the help. Can you suggest library or framework or tutorial to do this effectively. I intend to plug this functionality with MERN application..

Comment: You may take a look at this pen. They are using SVG, but this may be what you are looking for: [SVG use selecting a region in human body](https://codepen.io/onur_kaplan/pen/XaWeNK)

Comment: @enxaneta: This surely helps.Will use this as reference point.Any Javascript library you may suggest for this type of project